# Some questions about data structures and sort algorithm

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I'm learning about data structures and sort algorithm and I have some questions that I want to ask:

1. When we choose array and when we choose linked-list for sort algorithm
2. What sort algorithm we should use for small data and what for big data? I know that depends on the situation, we should choose available algorithm, but I can't understand the specifics.

Answer (score 3):

**Linked-list or array**

Array is the more common *choice*.

Linked-list is mostly used when your data is already in a linked-list, or you need it in a linked-list for your application.

Not that I've really seen justifiable cause to use one over the other (except that most sorting algorithms are focussed around arrays). Both can be sorted in O(n log n), at least with comparison-based sorting algorithms.

**When to use what**

With comparison-based sorting, [insertion sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort) is typically used for < ~10-20 elements, as it has low constant factors, even though it has O(n²) running time. For more elements, [quick-sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quick_sort) or [merge-sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) (both running in O(n log n)) or some derivation of either is typically faster (although there are other O(n log n) sorting algorithms).

Insertion sort also performs well (`O(n)`) on nearly sorted data.

For non-comparison-based sorting, it really depends on your data. Radix sort, bucket sort and counting sort are all well-known examples, and each have their respective uses. A brief look at their running time should give you a good idea of when they should be used. Counting sort, for example, is good if the range of values to be sorted is really small.

You can see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm) for a list of sorting algorithms.

Keep in mind that sorting less than like 10000 elements would be blazingly fast with any of these sorting algorithms - unless you need the absolute best performance, you could really pick whichever one you want.

Comment: Yes, for example radix sort can be very efficient with linked lists (no counting , no additional memory).

Comment: but array is difficult to add new element because size of array fixed,and when delete element,it's still hold memory

Comment: @john This is where a [dynamic array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_array) comes in - it keeps a little extra memory so it doesn't have to resize as often. **However**, if we're talking about a data structure where you want to keep it sorted while inserting / deleting elements, something like a [binary search tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree) tends to be a better option - this results in O(log n) per insert or delete, where both a linked-list and array have O(n) insert / delete cost.

Comment: @Dukeling Do you think about use vector to raplace an array ?,it's good ?

Comment: @john A vector usually refers to a dynamic array (although this may depend on the language - I know it does for C++, for example), so my above comment applies.

Comment: @Dukelingso,with small data,we should use a sort algorithm like select sort,insert sort?

Comment: @john Yes, if it's less than like 20 elements, insertion / selection sort is usually preferred.

Comment: just less than 20 element?,if i have 100 element,insertion / selection sort isn't usually preferred?

Comment: @john Merge sort or quick sort will most likely be faster in that case. But 100 elements will take like a millisecond to sort using any of these algorithms, so, unless you need the best performance, any is really fine.

Answer (score 1):

To my understanding, for both questions there is no definitive answer as both depend on the context of usage. However the following points might of importance:

1. If the records to be sorted are large and implemented as a value type, an array might be infavourable since exchange of records involves copying of data, which might be slower than redirecting references.
2. Some instance size for switching sort algorithms is usually found by experimentation in a specific context; perhaps Quicksort is used for the 'large' instances, whereas Merge Sort is used for 'small' instances, where the actual best separation between 'large' and 'small' is found by trying out in the specific context.

Comment: In most object-oriented languages (notable exception being C++), objects are actually object references, and moving them around is really fast.

Comment: @Jan Dvorak I was aware of that, I just wanted to point out that also structs could be used as entries to sort, in which case copying would be necessary.